# Where will the driver program execute when the spark job is executed in cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Let us suppose we have a Yarn cluster with 300 Data Nodes + 1 Name Node. If we execute our spark job in cluster mode, then, where will the driver program start? I have read that the driver program will reside inside the Application Master in cluster mode. so does it mean, that the driver will reside on any one of the 300 Data Nodes for that particular job?

For example, For each spark job there will be a driver program created. so let us suppose that the first job was executed in cluster mode and picked up 54th Data node to initiate the driver program there. If the next job is executed in cluster mode, will it pick up some random data node in the cluster and initiate the driver program there? Can anyone please clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, correct, the Driver will run on any one of your data nodes.

"In cluster mode, the Spark driver runs inside an application master process which is managed by YARN on the cluster, and the client can go away after initiating the application." https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/running-on-yarn.html